# Twitter Bootstrap 3: Making a container vertically center in a column

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap

I am using bootstrap 3 and I have a problem making the [a-formcon div] in the bootstrap column vertically center. Can someone help me propose a solution as I have tried many solutions and they don't seem to work.

This is my css:

```
 <style type="text/css">    
    #a-content{
      width:100%;
      height:auto;
    }

    #a-row{
      height:550px;
    }

    #a-left{
       border-right:1px solid #d1d3d4;
       height:100%;
       background-color:orange;
    }

    #a-left .a-formcon{
      max-width:380px;
      background-color:green;
      width:100%;
      margin-top: 10px;
      height: 400px;
    }

    #a-right{
      height:500px;
      height:100%;
    }
    </style>
```

This is my html block:

```
<div class="container" id="a-content">
       <div class="row" id="a-row">
            <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-5" id="a-left">
                  <div class="container a-formcon"> 

                  </div> 
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-7" id="a-right">.col-md-4</div>
       </div>
</div>
```

How can I make the a-formcon vertically center?

Please see the bootplay: http://bootply.com/98774

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Vertical positioning in CSS is tricky. You could use the new [Flexbox](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) properties, or use absolute positioning. Something like this:

1. Add `position: relative` to the containing `div` (`#a-left`)
2. Add `position: absolute` to the element you want vertically centered (`.a-formcon` in your case).
3. Set the `margin` to `0 auto` and the `left` and `right` properties to `0` to get it centered horizontally.
4. For the vertical centering, you can use the `calc` property to set the `top` value to 50% minus half the height of your element (assuming it is a fixed height): `top: calc(50% - 200px)`

Be aware that the `calc` property is not supported in older IE browsers. http://caniuse.com/#search=calc

Here's a fiddle of your example, updated with the positioning properties: http://jsfiddle.net/uLRgZ/

Comment: i will try this soon and will mark it solve. This looks like the solution and I am thinking of using to assign the height.